# getStaticHelper(action helper) getting parameters but giving error

Tags: php, zend-framework

I know how to pass parameters to a normal action helper that's called in the action itself. But this time I'm doing it in the Bootstrap using `HelperBroker::getStaticHelper`

```
$hooks = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('Test');
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($hooks);
```

I want to pass a parameter so I added the middle line

```
$hooks = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('Test');
$hooks->preDispatch($input);
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($hooks);
```

and the preDispatch is this

```
public function preDispatch($input){
    var_dump($input);
}
```

The strange thing is that var_dump shows me the input, but I also get this error

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for Test::preDispatch(), 

Notice: Undefined variable: input
```

Comment: Is it being called again somewhere without the argument?

Comment: @alex Hmm, good point. I will check into that.

Comment: What is $input defined as before you send it to the function?

Comment: @SenorPuerco it's just a string. I think @alex might be on to something, because maybe I should pass the parameter somehow when I'm creating `$hooks` but if I add `->preDispatch($input)` on the first line, the third line complains that `$hooks` isn't of type `Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract` so it had to be on 2 lines like I did, but this doesn't seem to be the right way still.

Answer (score 1):

preDispatch() is a hook called in dispatch loop. You shouldn't use it like this.

Zend_Controller_Action:

```
/**
 * Dispatch the requested action
 *
 * @param string $action Method name of action
 * @return void
 */
public function dispatch($action)
{
    // Notify helpers of action preDispatch state
    $this->_helper->notifyPreDispatch();

    ...
    $this->_helper->notifyPostDispatch();
}
```

Also this code is ambiguous:

```
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($hooks);
```

Action helper was registered within helper broker by getStaticHelper() method call

Answer (score 0):

You should make it like this:

```
class MyHelper extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper
{
    const BAR = false;

    public function preDispatch($request)
    {
        $this->ifBarExit(self::BAR);
    }

    public function ifBarExit($barValue)
    {
        if ($barValue) {
            exit('Bar was true!');
        }
    }
}
```

The preDispatch thinks it's first variable is request object - it's how it'S wired in the ZF's internals.

But now with the new function you can do:

```
 $helper = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('MyHelper');
 $variable = true;
 $helper->ifBarExit($variable); //won't exit
```

You shouldn't mess with the internal methods (i.e. call them) for your own vilain plans. If you want to inject something in the helper, don't pass it directly. Add member variable and sth like `$helper->setImportantThing($thing);` which will save it into `protected $_thing;` and then inside the method `echo $this->_thing;`